# FreeDos to Windows 7 on laptop

Tags: windows, freedos

I just bought a laptop (ASUS X553SA-XX203D) with FreeDos OS. I want to install a Windows 7 (tried with DVD and USB too) but when I wanted to boot the install disk it is crashing with blue screen and the following error msg: 0x00007e. I googled to find some solution but nothing worked. What should I do to be able to load the installer and install the Windows?

Thanks for you time.

Comment: Have you tried disabling secure boot from UEFI menu?

Comment: 1. How far did you have you come with the installation 2. Could you plz show us your bios/uefi config. for examp. via. screenshot 3. Could you show us a screenshot from your bluescreen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't install Windows 7 - blue screen](https://superuser.com/questions/1088387/cant-install-windows-7-blue-screen)