# Can't install Windows 7 - blue screen

Tags: windows-7, windows, freedos

Just bought a new notebook and I wanted to install Windows 7 (and 10) from freedos but as soon as I wanted to boot the installer (even from DVD or USB) it crashes with blue screen. The crash info is this: `0x00007e 0xffffffffc0000005 0x0000000000000000 0xfffff880009a8e58`.

I tried to turn off safe booting, but nothing changed. I hope you can give me a solution to install Windows.

Comment: Can you get into the bios? Try resetting everything there and make sure things like boot from usb or cd are selected.

Comment: It is selected. I can boot from DVD and USB too, but as soon as it tries to boot windows installer (windows loading files... windows logo appears) it is crashing.

Comment: Are you using a homemade iso image to boot from? Or are you using a factory type of Windows install disc. If you have any type of boot disc such as Hirens or BartPE I would give one of those a try to see if maybe the windows boot image on the DVD or USB is corrupted.

Comment: Also does your bios have an option anywhere for legacy boot? And does your USB drive boot on any other computer properly? Also what is the model of the laptop you are troubleshooting? Full model number would help.

Comment: I use a homemade ISO. I tried many types of boot image (W7, W8.1,W10) but nothing worked. The model is ASUS X553SA-XX203D.

Comment: Does that exact same usb or dvd boot image work on another computer? What method did you use to create and burn the image?

Comment: Yes, it works well. The pendrive is actually a new one. I used a program called Rufus to burn image files.

Comment: So it only bsod when it starts loading windows right? can you post the link to the windows image file you are using to burn. Are you using the same source for both the usb and the DVD. For now with the laptop lets just try to work with the DVD boot method instead of the USB.

Comment: What country are you trying this in? It could be an issue with a non English keyboard. When I searched the laptop model most of the spec pages for that specific number were in a different language.

Comment: I tried to boot with DVD but the same happened. "Windows loading files..." then the windows logo appears for a second, after that blue screen.

Comment: I try to use it in Hungary with hungarian keyboard (some special characters like éáűőúöüó etc.)

Comment: Will it boot normally without a boot disc in? Normally BSOD are attributed to either hardware or driver issues. Also it may help to know the source of the Windows boot disc. like where did you get the image from that you burned the disc from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the ISO file. If you have the same problem, try to use another ISO file (or another OS). I installed a Windows 10, and the problem disappeared.